# How does All In work?

Tags: all-in

I'm a bit confused as I try to learn Poker as to how All-In betting works. When I play on [thepokerpractice.com/](http://www.thepokerpractice.com/) it seems when the AI does All-In if everyone else folds they still leave the table. Why is this?

Comment: I tried to play it but i find it unrealistic. Maximum 4 players, where players sitout randomly till heads-up, when after you win it says you lost. Badly designed and not helpful, try a well established poker site with real people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the app is poorly designed. If you raise and win a pot your stack still goes down. The developer forgot to add the winning amount back to the winners stack. So as far as the game is concerned after an all in the player is out of the game as they have no chips.

As for all-in betting, if it's a no limit game you can bet everything you have at any point. You are just putting everything you have in the pot as your bet.

Comment: @Ryan if i recall, the bug is that chips can only be won if there is a showdown.  of course you can game this bug and still be successful, but what's the point?